# Source file is not able to convert from space to '_' character in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

In shell script, many files are coming as source and landing to specific directory but few files come as with space character which script got failed.

```
#!/bin/bash
SRC_DIR=/home/user123/data/src

while true
do
..............
file_proc()
{
file=$1
export JOB_SEQ=$2
......
file_src=${SRC_DIR}/${file}
............
}
done
```

In source file path, in UNIX terminal-

```
user123@hostname src]$ pwd
user123@hostname src]$ /home/user123/data/src
user123@hostname src]$ ls -lrt
  Jul 16 12:00         Test_data_123.csv
  Jul 16 12:00         Test data_234.csv
  Jul 16 12:01         Test_data_345.csv
  Jul 16 12:01         Test_data 456.csv
 .........................
```

I used `tr ' ' '_'` & `sed 's/ /_/g'` (means `file_src=${SRC_DIR}/${file} | tr ' ' '_'`) but it is not able to convert space in file name with `_` character using the shell script. I just want using shell script space in file name   will convert into `_` and then after go for process without shell script failure.

Comment: Can you show how `file_proc` is invoked within your script?

Comment: Please copy/paste your full script into http://shellcheck.net as the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs as I suspect that will identify some issues.

Comment: There should be no problem with filenames that contain spaces in the first place. Instead of changing those file names, fix the part of your script that is broken with respect to handling file names. (For example, it could be as simple as changing something like `foo $filename` to `foo "$filename"`.)

Comment: Why don't you simply permit spaces in filenames and make sure that your program process them properly? Note that a filename can contain any character except `/` and NUL. Further, you define a function `file_proc`, but never call it. Your loop will simply run forever, without doing anything. Finally, I don't understand the _files are coming as source _. What does it mean that a file "comes as source"? Please be a bit more clear in describing your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're putting a band-aid on a broken leg and your real problem is incorrect handling of file names that contain spaces elsewhere in your script (e.g. incorrect quoting), in which case converting spaces to underscores is not the solution. Without seeing that other part of your code or knowing why you're doing this, though, that's just a guess and we can't help you further with that.

Regarding what you specifically asked about - it sounds like you're doing this:

```
file_src=${SRC_DIR}/${file} | tr ' ' '_'
```

when you should be doing this:

```
file_src=$(printf '%s\n' "${SRC_DIR}/${file}" | tr ' ' '_')
```

or preferably:

```
file_src="${SRC_DIR}/${file}"
file_src="${file_src// /_}"
```

or even better, since `SRC_DIR` is a hard-coded part of your script and doesn't contain blanks, just:

```
file_src="${SRC_DIR}/${file// /_}"
```

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton for your answer. But unfortunately when i used your suggested answers then its not working for me. File from source path till now not converting into `_` character.

Comment: The code I posted WILL convert blanks to underscores so you must be calling `file_proc` without quoting it's arguments or doing something else wrong outside of the code you posted but without seeing a [mcve] (ie. minimal, complete script that demonstrates your problem) it's just guesswork. Did you do what I suggested and copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net? Did it identify any issues and, if so, have you fixed them?

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton, If i want to skip these type o files with space then how to do it ? Using exceptional handling.

Comment: asked new question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76724460/skip-those-files-which-contains-space-in-filename-in-shell-script